# How to link the libfc.a to a dynamic library?

Tags: library

I try to make the fc tools in EOS to be used in Java JNI, and write an interface to call the signature function.

However, it can only work on Mac with CMAKE flags SHARED, while in Ubuntu, it tells me that I can't link the static library libfc.a to my dynamic library and should use -fPIC to recompile the libfc.a.

And the libfc.a depends on some libraries like boost, then I have to recompile boost with -fPIC, that makes me frustrated.

Anybody know why macOS supports the compilation and Ubuntu can't?

Is it because all the static libraries in macOS are compiled with -fPIC?

And is there anyone who can help me to compile the crypto functions and provide me a dynamic library in Ubuntu?